# Did this stand do this to cause this?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

(Spoilers for Part 3)

So, while Jotaro is fighting the antagonist of Part 3 in Egypt, he realizes he can:

> stop time.

And he could do this all the time, he just didn't know about it.

With that said,

> Could Star Platinum stop time as Jotaro shot the gun, and grab the bullet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could have? Maybe. But did he do it? Probably not at that time.

The reason why Star Platinum was able to catch that bullet wasn't because Star Platinum stopped time, but just because of it's immense speed and precision.

There's also some speculation that Jotaro isn't really able to stop time in the same way that The World can but rather that he is just so fast that it *seems* like time has stopped.

Comment: The speculation is false due to the nature of  the (part 6 spoiler) Made in Heaven ark.